# In 1 Chronicles 4:39, Where Is Gedor At?

Tags: book-of-chronicles, yehuda, king-hezekiah

39 And they went to the entrance of Gedor, even unto the east side of the valley, to seek pasture for their flocks.

40 And they found fat pasture and good, and the land was wide, and quiet, and peaceable; for they of Ham had dwelt there of old.

41 And these written by name came in the days of Hezekiah king of Judah, and smote their tents, and the habitations that were found there, and destroyed them utterly unto this day, and dwelt in their rooms: because there was pasture there for their flocks.(1 Chronicles 4:39-41)

Question- Where is Gedor At? In the Hebrew, it seems to indicate that it is a town in the mountains of Judah, named with Halhul and Beth-zur (Joshua 15:58). However, other commentaries seem to disagree and place it in Arabia and in other places. Does anyone know where Gedor is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedera

Comment: ChatGPT says somewhere near Beis Lechem, in which case the "east side of the valley" refers to the Valley of Elah.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I do not know ChatGPT is considered valid. To me, it is just like using wikipedia as your source of information.

Comment: @shmuel It depends if it is hallucinating (this is possible) or if it using a source that it is not telling you about. So of course it is not reliable, but it does serve as food for thought and a basis for further investigation.